# Approximating structural typing in a Golang function

Tags: go, structural-typing

A library is providing me a series of types like this:

```
type T1 struct {
  n int
}
type T2 struct {
  n int
}
type T3 struct {
  n int
}
```

there is a marker interface like this

```
type S interface { 
   isS()
}

func (T1) isS() {}
func (T2) isS() {}
func (T3) isS() {}
```

I am trying to write a function:

```
func getN(s S) int {
  return s.n
}
```

Obviously, that won’t compile, and it shouldn’t.

What I am doing now is

```
func getN(s S) int {
  if t1, ok := s.(T1); ok {
     return t1
  }
  if t2, ok := s.(T2); ok {
     return t2
  }
  ...
}
```

That works, but it unbearably awful.  The library adds new T structures fairly often and it’s a disastrous violation of [open/closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).  Any tolerable language has a facility for this kind of situation; what is Golang’s?

Comment: You make a method `N` or `GetN` on each struct. The you don't need an `isS` method either. The only interesting and shared thing about these structs for the context that you're using them in is that they can provide a value "n", so you can provide a method for that in each struct.

Comment: *"what is Golang’s?"* -- reflection.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt — I didn’t write the functions.  Golang will not allow me to add methods to a struct I did not create.

Comment: Since `n` is not exported, you can't access it from another package; neither with a method like you suggest in the Q, nor with reflection. If the library doesn't give you a way to get to the value of N on a specific struct, you can't make it work across all structs

Answer (score 0):

Create a method on the interface that returns the type you are looking for. That will get it to compile correctly.

```
type S interface { 
   GetN()
}

func (T1) GetN() int {
// impl
}
func (T2) GetN() int  {
// impl
}
func (T3) GetN() int  {
// impl
}
```

then if you still need your interesting function that takes an interface, you can do this:

```
func getN(s S) int {
  return s.GetN()
}
```